# veth between two network process namespaces?

Tags: process, namespace, veth

I created two namespaces: `unshare -mnpf bash --norc -is host1` (& host2)
At the prompt of host1, I run:

```
ip link add name host1-eth0 type veth peer name host2-eth0 netns <host2-pid>
```

But it fails with RTNETLINK answers: `No such process`

How could I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Proccesses in a pid namespace can't see processes in parent pid namespaces.

So i'm pretty sure you will have to create the veth from the main pid namespace, not from one of the child namespaces.

I'm not sure if you can create both ends of a veth in specified namespaces or if you will have to create at least one of them in the main namesace and move it to the child namespace.